# Find folder without permission inheritance

Tags: windows, file-permissions, icacls

How can I recursively find which folder doesn't have permission inheritace enabled?

Comment: SO duplicate: [Getting names of folders that do not inherit permissions](//stackoverflow.com/q/25126877)